# Is this sentence grammatically correct (version 2)?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, british-english

I have been trying to write this sentence for a while and I am wondering whether this is grammatically correct?

*The story nicely flows and the transition never stops the reader cold.*

I also attempted to write:

*The story nicely flows and the transition never stops cold.*

I read the usage:

- stop (one) cold (redirected from stop you cold)
- stop cold

Both seems to be correct? Which one I should use or its just a matter of preference?

Answer (score 4):

In everyday speech or writing, *nicely flows* is out of order.

I can't cite a prescriptive rule, but as a native speaker (US), I would always say "flows nicely" in your context. Perhaps for some poetic reason, or perhaps to emphasize *flows* as opposed to some other verb, it might be ordered the way you have it, *nicely flows*, but it's hard to construct even such a poetic or emphatic sentence that doesn't sound awkward. ("I'm telling you, it nicely *flows*! It doesn't nicely meander or nicely stumble!")

*Never stops the reader cold* seems fine to me, although the meaning is a bit nebulous. I take it to mean the story never jars the reader violently out of the enjoyable experience of reading it.

Comment: I'm a native speaker of British English and I would always say "flows nicely" rather than "nicely flows" in this context as well. The reason is, I believe, that reversing the words splits the verb from the subject in an awkward way and applies to most other verb-adverb combinations. For example a cyclist will "pedal hard" rather than "hard pedal". As you say the order can be reversed for effect or emphasis as in "She will loudly sing his praises". This used to be criticised as a split infinitive (think "to boldly go" from Star Trek) but is much more widely accepted now.

Comment: Excellent analysis and correct use of US English. If I could find a proper source then I would have added an answer myself. The use of *stops cold* would indeed stop the reader cold. "Stops *the reader* cold" is not the most typical but is fine in your usage.